# How to include a if condition inside where clause in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following method:

```rb
def add_books(year, industry, author_id=nil)
  Books.where(publication_year:year, author: author_id)
end
```

How can I update the query to not filter by `author_id` if it is not passed?

Comment: Please go over https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers when you have time. Noticed you have some questions with answers where you did not accept one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
def add_books(year, industry, author_id = nil)
  conditions = { publication_year: year }
  conditions[:author_id] = author_id if author_id.present?

  Books.where(conditions)
end
```

But, the name of the method `add_books` implies a
`create` which you do not have. Also the `industry` is not used. Something is fishy :)